# Privliages on test app

Tags: facebook

Hey guys i have developed a facebook app which uses the permission `read_mailbox`.When i coded my app and used the app it says the app neeeds to be reviewed for getting the permission `read_mailbox`.I have submitted my app for review.But i didnt get review after 2 days ..I cant wait anymore ..I have made a test app and when i used that it says the same thing..I have heard that using the test app will have all the privliages.Is it true ??..Or the test app work only if facebook approve the permission ??..

Hope you guys can help me out ...Thanks

Comment: You can use your admin user to test it... Then you can just ignore the warning message.

Comment: @Tobi am the admin of the app ..the thing is that i want to test my ap with all privliages ..how can i do it ??

Comment: You can already test it if you're using the admin user, like I wrote.

Comment: When i used the test app it shows error in console like read_mailbox not granted

Comment: what i want is that i need to use all the privliages and test my app to check if its working or not

Comment: I can't tell how you implemented your app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review states that `...your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.` Given that, I don't really understand your problem

Comment: @Tobi but when i used the test app it says read_mail box permission needs to be granted

Comment: Yes, I can read. And as you didn't post ANY code, it's impossible to help you there. As I said multiple times, if you're using the app admin as test user and grant the permission, it should work from Facebook perspective. What you do in your app is invisible to us.

Comment: This is the code which am using http://pastebin.com/ppEFJ3TT

Comment: sorry its read_mailbox

Comment: can you know about it ?

Answer (score 0):

The code here (http://pastebin.com/8MLfiQRC) works like a charm for me.

You wrote

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,read_maillist" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

instead of

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,read_mailbox" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

If the Permission dialog pops up, just click on ok (http://imgur.com/AyOZUhf).

Comment: please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008759/retreive-the-number-of-messages-send

Comment: Sorry, I'm not your personal Facebook support. Did my answer help you? If yes, please accept it.