# Retrieve the number of messages send

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In facebook js sdk app development..I need to find the number of facebook messages send from the inbox. The code which I am using is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
   <body>

<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
  // they are logged into this app or not.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}


}



  function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
appId      : '289533237896176',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

  };


  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me/inbox',function(response) {  for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
var thread = response.data[i];

for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
    var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message;

    console.log(comment);


}
}



}



);


}

</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,read_mailbox" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

```
<div id="status">

<div id="fb-root"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This script successfully retrieves the  number of first 10 messages ..what I need is to display the number of messages in total ..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically applies paging to all API requests that return lists of items. If you do not specify page size FB will apply it's default size. From your example it looks like 10 items per page.
For moving to the next page you should use `response.paging.next` field - it contains ready to use url generated by FB to access the next page. If you reach the last page `response.paging` field will be null.

[More reading about paging from FB specification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#paging)

---

Additionally if you want to adjust page size to e.g. 50 items per page you can add `limit=50` to your request. Code will look like:

```
FB.api('/me/inbox?limit=50', ...
```

Comment: the thing which i want is to get the number of words from the messages send

Comment: I cannot see if you count words there - you display them into console instead. Anyway to count total number of all comments you need to iterate through comments from other pages, this means you should do extra API calls to access the rest of comments

Comment: see i want the words of the messages ..i succefully retrieve the message but i need to fing the number of words in those messages

Comment: then use `comment.split(' ').length` for number of words in single comment

Comment: i want to find the number of words in the whole comment ..i have tried it but it reteieves only for one comment ..i need to find the sum of whole words in the comment

Comment: var counter=0;
for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
    var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message;

    counter += comment.split(' ').length;
}
console.log(counter);

Comment: it didnt helped ..it shows like 112,115 ..what i need is their total